# Are all pointers towards contiguous chunks of memory automatically indexed?/Scenario where this isn't the case?

Tags: c

I'm wondering if it'll be dangerous to move on with the assumption that "whenever you dynamically allocate a pointer, it'll be automatically indexed and be accessible no matter what the type it comes from". Meaning an array is just a contiguous chunk of memory that can consist of anything and the syntax to create an array of function pointers, an array of arrays of arrays, ect all follow the same principles.

Is there any situation where this is not the case?

And does this mean if I malloc a pointer towards something, I can always access it by using index? Ie. anything that can be dereferenced can be accessed by index? Am I thinking about this the wrong way or lacking some type of fundamental understanding?

And also, how is an index created by a computer? I'm thinking the first memory address is subtracted by itself, the next in line is subtracted by the starting, ect-- but there's probably something the computer does that is far more convenient. But for this, it would make sense for why if you move a pointer forward, index 0 is wherever said pointer is, but if all indexes are created through pointer arithmetic, that raises a few other concerns. Ie. is the index stored somehow or recalculated every time it's needed?

Comment: An array is a contiguous chunk of memory. You can use pointer arithmetic to access pointers and arrays at your own risk (in C).

Comment: you have too much questions and your first paragraph is not very clear. Please ask 1 question per SO question and show us some code of what you mean.

Comment: @o_weisman Why at your own risk? Is this inadvisable?

Comment: The compiler could check or create boundary check when you define an array and access the elements using [] operator (warning or error in compiling or runtime if it is indicated into the flags)! Any other uses (array items accessed using a pointer or a pointer which content is accessed referencing it by indexed array) the boundaries should be checked or if check boundaries are disabled!! (-Warray-bounds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a lot of confusion and you post is all over the place. Lets see if I can shed some light. I will try to keep it as simple as possible. The subject is pretty complex once you start to dive into it, but for start you don't need to know all the details and all the exceptions.

> whenever you dynamically allocate a pointer

if you refer to `int* p = malloc(n * sizeof(int))` then here you don't dynamically allocate a pointer. You dynamically **allocate memory**. `malloc` allocates memory (if it can) and then returns a pointer to the beginning of the that memory. You save that value (the address of the start of the allocated memory) to the variable `p`. A lot of confusion I saw in programmers learning pointers come from the unfortunate expressions "allocate pointer" and "free pointer". You need to shift your mental model. You allocate and free memory, not pointers. When you understand this it will help you out a lot (e.g. when trying to figure out when `free` is needed)

> whenever you dynamically allocate a pointer, it'll be automatically
>   indexed

It doesn't matter to what the pointer points, e.g. dynamically allocated memory or to the memory of global variable, or to the memory of a local storage variable or whatever. The C++ syntax depends only on the type of the expressions.

> it'll be automatically indexed

not clear what you mean by that. If `p` is a pointer and `i` is an integer type then `p[i]` is valid syntax and is equivalent to `*(p + i)`

> and be accessible no matter what the type it comes from

No. In C there is the so called strict aliasing rule. In short it says that an object of type `T` can be aliased and accessed only though a pointer of type `T*` or `char*`. The reason behind this has to do with optimizations.

> Meaning an array is just a contiguous chunk of memory that can consist
>   of anything

That is true only a lower level. I.e. on hardware level and assembly level. `C` has it's own rules that as I've said above prevents type aliasing. E.g. you can't treat an array an `int` as an array of `short`.

> and the syntax to create an array of function pointers, an array of
>   arrays of arrays, ect all follow the same principles.

The syntax may be the same (more or less), but again the stric aliasing rule makes aliasing a type via another type illegal.

> Is there any situation where this is not the case?

Almost all of the situations.

> if I malloc a pointer towards something, I can always access it by
>   using index?

Yes. We are circling back. Again for `p` a pointer type e.g. `T*` and `i` an integer type `p[i]` is valid syntax. To be valid semantics `p + i`there needs to be an object of type `T` at the address `p + i`.

> anything that can be dereferenced can be accessed by index?

Yes. `p[i]` is equivalent with `*(p + i)`

> And also, how is an index created by a computer? I'm thinking the
>   first memory address is subtracted by itself, the next in line is
>   subtracted by the starting, ect-- but there's probably something the
>   computer does that is far more convenient. But for this, it would make
>   sense for why if you move a pointer forward, index 0 is wherever said
>   pointer is, but if all indexes are created through pointer arithmetic,
>   that raises a few other concerns. Ie. is the index stored somehow or
>   recalculated every time it's needed?

I don't understand all your points, but you are thinking way too much about this.

It is very simple. A pointer holds a value that represents an address in memory. You write `p[i]` in your code and then run the program and it reaches this line and the program executes this line. At this point there is a value for `p` and a value for `i`. To compute the address where the object is located is just a matter of simple arithmetics:

For instance:

```
(1) int* p;

(2) p = malloc(<expression>);

//...

(3) int i;

(4) int i = <expression>;

(5) p[i];
```

Assume `sizeof(int) == 4`.

Lines `(1)` and `(3)` declare the variables `p` and `i`.

When the program is ran:

line (2): malloc allocates memory and returns the address to the begging of it. Let's say that address is `0xFF0000`

line (4): `i` is assigned an integer value. Let's say `5`

line (5): `p[i]` is equivalent to `*(p + i)` so in order to access the object first its address must be computed. The object we accessed is the `i`th element - 5th element in our example - from the address `p` - `0xFF0000`. Each element occupies `4` bytes (because the size of 1 element is `sizeof(int)`). So the address is computed as this:

```
0xFF0000 + 5 * 4
```

the address `0xFF0014` is obtained (*). Finally to evaluate `p[i]` the object of type `int` from address `0xFF0014` is obtained. (read to or written to, depending on the operation. In our example the result is ignored).

(*) If you are confused, it's because of the mix of base 10 and base 16:

```
0xFF0000 + 5 * 4 = 0xFF0000 + 20 = 0xFF0000 + 0x14 = 0xFF0014
(20 == 0x14)
```